# Store a session information - one more Core Data table or separate session-file in "key-value" format (YAML, JSON)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, key-value-store

I have a Session class which I want to hold and store app's current session information (like lastLocation, remoteSessionToken, ...)

I have default Core Data setup with a bunch of tables and the most obvious solution I see is to create one more table "session" with two string fields: 'field' and 'value' and store session information to this table in way like I store any information to other tables

```
  'field'             'value'
lastLocation        46.68,34.18
removeSessionToken  au987asdv7tta487tv9b
...
```

Also, I know I could have this done using a special separate file for settings fx in YAML or JSON format but this would lead to a logical inconsistency with having both Core Data database and a file.

Is there any recommended approach for holding and persisting session information?

Answer (score 2):

Unless something like the following applies, put it in user defaults or in a special purpose file in the documents directory:

- You have many sessions and need to search or filter them based on some kind of predicate
- You have more than one session and sessions have some kind of relationship to specific objects in the data store.

It's not a "logical inconsistency" to use Core Data and separate files. Do what makes sense. It's not likely to make sense to keep this information in your data store, so don't do it unless you have some compelling reason.

If the information could be considered sensitive, put it in the keychain.

Also, it's *extremely* ugly to create a generic container entity in Core Data. Using `field` and `value` fields like you describe is not a good design decision.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's not sensitive information, I would be consistent and use Core Data. A more obscure place would be to put it in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I also think I should go with CD variant, but want to hear if there are any alternative answers to this question.